# Error using circuitikz, "Missing number, treated as zero"

Tags: circuitikz

I have this code:

```
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
 \usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
 \usepackage{dblfloatfix}
 \usepackage{fixltx2e}
 \usepackage{commath}

 \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] \draw [dashed]
        (0,4) node[above]{\Large{e}}
        (2,1.5) node[right]{\Large{q}}
        to[short] (0,0) node[below]{\Large{f}}
        to[short] (-2,1.5) node[left]{\Large{p}}
        to[short] (0,4)
;
\draw

(0,4)       to[short, i={$ $}] (1.1464,3.5536) 
(1.5,3.2)   circle[radius=0.5cm] node{\LARGE{G}}
(1.8536,2.8536) to[short, i={1}] (2,1.1)
(0,4)       to[short, i_<={$ $}] (-0.75,2.5) 
(-0.75,2)   circle[radius=0.5cm] node{\LARGE{R}}
(-0.75,1.5) to[short, i_<={$ $}] (0,0)
;
\draw [dashed]
(-2,1.5) to (-1,1.5)
(-0.5,1.5) to (0.5,1.5)
(1,1.5) to (2,1.5)


;
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{CODASA}
\label{f_3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I change the number in this line `(1.8536,2.8536)    to[short, i={1}] (2,1.1)` to `...(2,1.2)` it gives me the `undefined control sequence` and `missing number...` errors.

UPDATE: The error disappears if I don't use the `i={1}`, like `(1.8536,2.8536)  to[short] (2,1.1) to ...(2,1.2)` but I need to draw the arrow.

Comment: unrelated but size commands don't take an argument so `{\Large{e}}` could/should be `{\Large e}`

Comment: if I add `\documentclass{article}` to try your code, it generates `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.38 \caption
             {CODASA}
? 
! Too many }'s.` please fix the example to generate the error that you are asking about.

Comment: Adding a `\documentclass` and removing the caption, label and `\end{figure}`, your code works fine.

Comment: Its a bug.  There is a calculation in \pgf@circ@drawcurrent which covers all angles except 275 to 285 (probably a typo)..

Answer (score 2):

So, how does one go about reporting a bug?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
 \usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
 \usepackage{dblfloatfix}
 \usepackage{fixltx2e}
 \usepackage{commath}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@circ@drawcurrent{
    \pgfextra{
        \edef\pgf@circ@ffffff{\pgf@circ@direction}
        \def\pgfcircmathresult{\expandafter\pgf@circ@stripdecimals\pgf@circ@ffffff\pgf@nil}

        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >4 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <86
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                \def\pgf@circ@dir{north west} \else \def\pgf@circ@dir{south east}
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >85 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <95
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                \def\pgf@circ@dir{west} \else \def\pgf@circ@dir{east} 
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >94 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <176
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                 \def\pgf@circ@dir{south west}\else \def\pgf@circ@dir{north east}
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >175 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <185
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                  \def\pgf@circ@dir{south}\else\def\pgf@circ@dir{north}
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >184 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <266
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                 \def\pgf@circ@dir{south east}\else\def\pgf@circ@dir{north west}
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >265 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <275
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                 \def\pgf@circ@dir{east}\else \def\pgf@circ@dir{west}
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >274 \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <356
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                  \def\pgf@circ@dir{north east}\else\def\pgf@circ@dir{south west}
            \fi
        \fi\fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult <5
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                 \def\pgf@circ@dir{north}\else\def\pgf@circ@dir{south} 
            \fi
        \fi
        \ifnum\pgfcircmathresult >355
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
                 \def\pgf@circ@dir{north}\else\def\pgf@circ@dir{south} 
            \fi
        \fi

        \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@below
            \def\pgf@circ@bipole@current@label@where{-90}
        \else
            \def\pgf@circ@bipole@current@label@where{+90}
        \fi
    }


        \pgfextra{  \def\pgf@temp{short} \edef\pgf@circ@temp{\ctikzvalof{bipole/kind}} }

        \ifx\pgf@circ@temp\pgf@temp % caso di corrente (centrata) su un corto
            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@current@backward
                { (\tikztotarget) -- 
                    node [currarrow, pos=\ctikzvalof{current/distance}, sloped,  allow upside down] (Iarrow) {} 
                  (\tikztostart)  }
            \else
                { (\tikztostart) -- 
                    node [currarrow, pos=\ctikzvalof{current/distance}, sloped,  allow upside down] (Iarrow) {} 
                  (\tikztotarget)  }
            \fi

        \else % altri bipoli - e quindi tra nodo e target

            \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@iscurrent
                \ifpgf@circuit@europeancurrent
                    \pgf@circ@drawnormalcurrent
                \else 
                \fi
            \else
                \pgf@circ@drawnormalcurrent
            \fi
        \fi

    \ifpgf@circuit@bipole@iscurrent
         node [anchor=\pgf@circ@dir] at (\ctikzvalof{bipole/name}.\pgf@circ@bipole@current@label@where) 
            { \pgf@circ@finallabel{current/} }
    \else
        (Iarrow.\pgf@circ@bipole@current@label@where) node [anchor=\pgf@circ@dir]   
            { \pgf@circ@finallabel{current/} } 
    \fi

}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}

 \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] \draw [dashed]
        (0,4) node[above]{\Large{e}}
        (2,1.5) node[right] (Q) {\Large{q}}
        to[short] (0,0) node[below]{\Large{f}}
        to[short] (-2,1.5) node[left]{\Large{p}}
        to[short] (0,4)
;
\draw

(0,4)       to[short, i={$ $}] (1.1464,3.5536) 
(1.5,3.2)   circle[radius=0.5cm] node{\LARGE{G}}
(1.8536,2.8536) to[short, i={$1$}] (2,1.2)
(0,4)       to[short, i_<={$ $}] (-0.75,2.5) 
(-0.75,2)   circle[radius=0.5cm] node{\LARGE{R}}
(-0.75,1.5) to[short, i_<={$ $}] (0,0)
;
\draw [dashed]
(-2,1.5) to (-1,1.5)
(-0.5,1.5) to (0.5,1.5)
(1,1.5) to (2,1.5)


;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for spotting it!

You can make a pull request here, if you want: https://github.com/mredaelli/circuitikz

Or I'll just fix it myself when I have time.